# Which version of Jenkins 2.x is stable for upgrading from 1.x

Tags: jenkins

Am currently using jenkins 1.642.3 and planning to upgrade to 2.x version. Could anyone please suggest what version of 2.x is stable with all features and where I can get more details.

Thanks
Ashif

Answer (score 1):

There are the [LTS (Long Term Support) releases](https://jenkins.io/download/lts/), which are considered more stable and receive bug fixes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen.Is there any version no's like 2.1,2.2 to 2,64.Could you please suggest me the exact version which is stable.

Comment: The current LTS version announced on the [Jenkins download page](https://jenkins.io/download/) is 2.46.3. Use that, it will make you happy.

Comment: Thanks a lot stephane..Sure i will make a note of that.

Comment: Hello Again, As of now am using LTS 1.642.3 only...will it affect if i suddenly upgrade to latest 2.46.3 or i need to upgrade step by step.Pls suggest me on this.

Comment: Nobody knows. You have to try it (to figure out, which plugins are still compatible). In general, v2 is not breaking more than usually.

Comment: Hi @Ashif.I think we are on the same boat.To which version are you able to migrate now?what is the jenkins-core.jenkins-test-harness and jenkins-war versions are you using.CAn you reply at the earliest bcoz am kind of stuck

Answer (score 0):

The first LTS release of Jenkins was 2.7.1 and according to this post the upgrade from 1.x should be seamless:  https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/07/07/jenkins-2/

There's detailed steps to follow on the upgrade page: https://jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.7/